# Sort by Month and Year in Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm having trouble sorting by month/year format in R.
I have data in a `%m/%Y` format but in trying to use

```
df_prod<-df_prod[order(as.Date(df_prod$date,format="%m/%Y")),]
```

The data frame is not sorting. I'm getting a text-like ordering (01/2000,01/2001,01/2002)

Additional details:
I'm performing an `dplyr` aggregation on a dataframe that was nicely sorted in `%m/%Y` format:

```
df_prod<-df %>%
  group_by(date,comp_id) %>%
  summarise(a_prod=prod(1+TRT)-1)
```

Thank you

Comment: Most likely as.Date(df_prod$date,format="%m/%Y") is producing an invalid date and thus the order function is sorting based on a string value.

Comment: As dave2e mentions, "%m/%Y" is not a date. You need to include a day in order to have a valid date. The easiest solution is to paste "/1" at the beginning and use "%d/%d/%Y". This has been asked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @lmo has already mentioned that using just `%m/%Y` will not create a valid date. One solution is to use `as.yearmon` from `zoo` package.

```
library(zoo)    
df_prod<-df_prod[order(as.yearmon(df_prod$date,format="%m/%Y")),]
```

Answer (score 0):

`%m/%Y` is a tricky starting format for a date, if that's what you ultimately need:

grab date components from the string:

```
aa <- format(Sys.Date(), "%m/%Y")
m <- as.numeric(substr(aa, 1, 2))
y <- as.numeric(substr(aa, 4, 8))
```

Then you can paste them together into a date format and sort:

```
as.Date(paste(y, "-", m, "-01", sep = ''))
```